# Merge, but don't merge

Tags: git

I had branched from master and made a plethora of directory changes and moving of files in a project.

After I branched, another developer added a unit test to one of the files in its original location on their branch and merged back to master.

If I try to merge from master to my branch and back again, basically every single file has moved, so it will make a mess.

What I'd like to do is tell git to merge master to my branch, but only do it in bookkeeping. Leave the state of the files exactly how they are in my branch. Then let me manually add the differences from the added unit test, and merge back to master.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180316-00/?p=98255:

> You can use the `-s ours` option to `git merge` to indicate that you want no code changes from the merge; you are doing this only for bookkeeping purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If the change regarding the added unit test lies in a single commit (say, with SHA1 `1234567`), you could try to do:

```
git checkout your-branch
git cherry-pick 1234567
# which might raise some conflict to solve
# then
git checkout master
git merge your-branch
```

See the doc of [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- You have committed (and published) your changes to your branch
- You have fetched and/or pulled the changes down from master

You could simply rebase your branch on top of master to:

- Get the changes that they did
- Reapply the changes that you did, including moving the files

```
git fetch
git checkout my-work-branch
git rebase origin/master
```

This will cause you to merge the changes in at that point.  You're going to have to "merge" in either scenario, but this is the cleanest approach to ensure that their work makes it into the code properly.